# Hiragana keyboard on Telephone Huawei P8 Lite

Tags: languages, huawei, gboard

I have a problem and can not find the solutionn by myself.

I want to keep the language I have on my telephone, BUT would like to have an extra language only on my keyboard. Japanese language (Hiragana)
I wold like to switch easily etween these languages. Now I use English as an extra language, but Japanese is not listed on the Huawei P8 Lite.

Who can help me out, please?

Kind regards

Comment: Are you open to alternative keyboard, such as [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin) and [Google Japanese IME](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.japanese)? I don't know if it will work on your device though, but on my Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1, there's a shortcut on the keyboard to switch the language input. Otherwise, just use Google Japanese IME as the main keyboard, as it also include romaji (alphabet) input.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. It is not a problem to install an app, but I avoid installing ones who ask information  and access to photo's and such things, also in-app. I have seen google Japanese language including writing in signs (yay!), but the problem is they want access to pictures and so. This is why I did not install. WHen you find me a better option, I am happy! Thank you!

Comment: Which Android version is running on your device? If it's Android 6+, you could revoke those unwanted permissions with the integrated permission manager. With 4.3+ that could be done using AppOps as well, there are [AppOps FrontEnds](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_1027) available.